# Using ISNULL function is not giving proper value

Tags: sql-server, isnull

I am working with one query in MSSQL like this:

`select company_id,isshowable from company where company_id in (1,2);`

It will give results like:

```
 company_id | isshowable    
      1     |    NULL  
      2     |    true
```

Here, company_id 1 has isshowable = NULL value. When I apply the `isnull` function with this query:

```
select isshowable, company_id
from company
where company_id in (1,2)
    and (isshowable='true' OR isshowable = ISNULL(isshowable,'true'));
```

It gives only one record which has company_id = 2. Why is the ISNULL function is not replacing NULL value with 'true'?

My requirement is that both records should be fetched from the database, and NULL values should be replaced with 'true'.

What should be a proper way to achive this ?

Answer (score 1):

Because `NULL` <> `'true'`.

Your `WHERE` clause:

```
isshowable = ISNULL(isshowable, 'true'))
```

returns false if `isshowable` is `NULL`. Remember that `ISNULL` function returns the 2nd argument if the first argument is `NULL`. So in this case, your `ISNULL` returns `true`. But the left hand side of the equation is still `NULL`, so it became:

```
`NULL` = 'true'
```

which, as you know, is `false`, for the purpose of the `WHERE` clause. *(Note that SQL Server uses three-valued logic, so NULL = false is really = UNKNOWN)*

To achieve your desired outcome, your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE
    company_id in (1,2) 
    AND (isshowable = 'true' OR isshowable IS NULL)
```

Comment: `UNKNOWN`, not `FALSE`. Easily demonstrated by wrapping these expressions with `NOT (<expression>)` and observing that they don't become `TRUE`. SQL uses three-valued logic.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Why did I miss that? Thanks

Comment: thank you felix with help.it was my mistake to understand. thank you